# C++ ofstream System.AccessViolation

Tags: c++

I have a problem. I'm writing to a log file, but when I do the application throws:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in ****

Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

The code (unmanaged) I'm using is this one:

```
inline bool writeLog(string message)
{
    ofstream myfile;

    myfile.open(mStrSource.c_str(), ios::in | ios::out | ios::app);

    if(!myfile.is_open())
    {
        throw "Unable to open the file: " + mStrSource;
    }

    myfile << "TESTE" << endl;

    myfile.close();

    return true;
};
```

When receiving this error, the code points to the _Lock() of file fstream:

```
virtual void __CLR_OR_THIS_CALL _Lock()
        {   // lock file instead of stream buffer
        if (_Myfile)
            _CSTD _lock_file(_Myfile);
        }
```

Other info:

Developed under VS2010 (Incially the project was Winx32 but now it's Winx64) (.NET Framework 4).

The open() method of ofstream creates the file and the file is writable but throws the exception when try's to write on the file.

Thank you guys in advanced.

Comment: have you checked the file permissions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check to make sure your application has rights to write to a file in that location.  A standard user in Windows cannot access the whole file system (especially for writing).  Either require the app to have admin rights (not recommended for "normal" apps) or write to a place that standard users can get to (e.g. My Documents directory).

Also, make sure the file is not opened for exclusive use by another app like Excel or Word.  They have a habit of locking files when opening them.

Another thing to look at is during development, sometimes the .NET runtime/VS debugger will leave a file locked that you were working with after a crash.  Try closing/reopening Visual Studio to help with that.

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys,

For future notice, the problem was related to the configuration of the project. When I converted the project from vs2008 to vs2010, from .net 3.5 to .net 4 and from x32 to x64 something didn't quite go right.

So I reverted everything back and converted again in a more controlled environment and now i can open/write/close files without a problem.

Thanks anyway guys.